# select/options ng-model is not bound with ng-selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2srwhtb/)

I have this AngularJS html for a select/options with a selected item by default according to an external value (selectedGroup). There should be an empty option for this list ('-ROOT-' option):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="newDoor.groupId">
    <option value="">-ROOT-</option>
    <option ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-value="group.id" ng-selected="group==selectedGroup">
        {{group.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**The problem is:**
when ng-selected condition causes an option to be selected, the ng-model is not affected by this select, but when u change the option, ng-model get the value. How to let the value of ng-model take the auto selected option directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in the controller by predefining it first as a new object and then putting the value when you putting the value for selectedGroup.

Code:

```
function doorsTreeController($scope) {
    $scope.newDoor = {};
    $scope.groups = [{
        name: 'G1',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'G2',
        id: 2
    }, {
        name: 'G3',
        id: 3
    }, {
        name: 'G4',
        id: 4
    }];
    $scope.selectedGroup = $scope.groups[1];
    $scope.newDoor.groupId = $scope.selectedGroup.id;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2srwhtb/1/)

OR

have a ng-init in html and rest of your code as is.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='doorsTreeController'>
        <select class="form-control" ng-init="newDoor.groupId = selectedGroup.id" ng-model="newDoor.groupId">
            <option value="">-ROOT-</option>
            <option ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-value="group.id" ng-selected="group==selectedGroup">{{group.name}}</option>
    </select>Selected groupId is: {{newDoor.groupId}}</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2srwhtb/2/)

Comment: In both cases you have an ugly blank item at the start of the array that disappears when you select something (which could confuse the user). This is because the controller or `ngInit` code will run before the code inside the `ng-repeat`, and hence there will be no corresponding input for the value of "2". It's not a big deal, but this, and the brevity of the alternate solution, would mean I strongly recommend just using the directive angular has built-in for this.

Comment: which blank item you refering to? i do not have it in any of th demos?

Comment: ngInit won't work with me while the selectedGroup will change according to some processing in the page. The first solution works ok, even though I prefered to have it solved using sth like ngChanged.

Comment: @V31 run the demo, then click the drop down - at the top of the list there is a blank item. It disappears as soon as you select something else. I'm using chrome, it may be different in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). ngOptions is designed to populate select inputs, using a microsyntax passed as an attribute.

For example, in your case, you could use the following:

```
<select ng-model="newDoor.groupId" 
        ng-options="group.id as group.name for group in groups">
```

This would list every `group` in `groups` using `group.id` as the value and displaying `group.name` as the name. It handles the change detection for you.

The only extra thing you would need to do, is account for this requirement:

> There should be an empty option for this list ('-ROOT-' option):

I have done this by adding another option to the front of your `groups` array:

```
$scope.groups.unshift({ name: '-ROOT-', id: -1 });
```

Finally, to make sure something real is selected when the scope initialises, this line sets `newDoor.groupId`:

```
$scope.newDoor = { groupId: $scope.groups[0].id }
```

See an [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2srwhtb/4/)

Comment: Yes, I moved to ng-options. but I didn't like the idea of changing the array by pushing an item with -1 value.

Comment: @AlBaraaSh You don't have to use `-1`, you can use `null` if you like, but then you get an empty item in the array (as with the solution you accepted). Having an array on your scope with all of the selectable values is much neater in my opinion than having some selectable items in the scope, and some in the markup - it means you have a better separation of concerns.

Comment: Regarding separation of concerns, you are right, but the options array in my real application is not dedicated for this select only, this is why I didn't like to change the values of it. Regarding the empty item in the select options array, I don't know why it is appearing in the demo, while it is not in my real application also.