# Angular.js: How do I initialize the ng-model of a <select> element to be the ng-selected option's value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My select looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="model.string">
     <option ng-repeat="option in options"
             ng-bind-html="option.name"
             ng-selected="option.name === 'Selected Option'"
             ng-value="option.value">
     </option>
</select>
```

There is no way of knowing which options's name is 'Selected Option' and I cant use ng-options. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485346/how-do-i-get-the-ng-model-of-a-select-tag-to-get-the-initially-selected-option) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938154/select-options-ng-model-is-not-bound-with-ng-selected) does not solve my problem.

What can I do for model.string to be the value of the initially selected value instead of undefined or whatever it was initialized as?

**EDIT:** [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bk7mfAoVJQHCMFjAM84Q?p=preview)

Comment: Why can't you use `ng-options`? Seems to me like that would be the best solution.

Comment: Did you tried ng-init? ng-init="model.string='yourVal'"

Comment: I use a combination of optgroups to map a sometimes 2D, sometimes 1D Array into a select. And no, even though stated in one of the answers I linked to it changes the selected value but not the model (as stated in that answer's comments).

Comment: `ng-selected="option.name === model.string"`?

Comment: model.string is supposed to have the value of the selected option. The selected option is not the one with the value of model.string.

Comment: why not this way ? http://plnkr.co/edit/t4vIjxjxHf6UoZovq3ce?p=preview

Comment: You should use `ng-options` to render select options. If you want to have an initial value for model, assign it  in your controller like in the official documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Because I dont know which option will be the selected one @Daredzik
As I said, ng-options lacks features I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use ng-options, you'll have to initialize your model "by yourself", getting the value selected in your options collection :

```
 $scope.getChosenOption = function()
 {
   for (var i in $scope.options)
    if ($scope.options[i].selected === 'selected')
     return $scope.options[i].name;
 };

$scope.selected = $scope.getChosenOption();
```

Plus, I think you made a typo using "model.string" in your view instead of "selected" $scope variable.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3SrdSy3oJJQHFfKWZky?p=preview) is your Plunker updated

Comment: Is there really no other way? Seems odd to me that I have to iterate the array a second time (once in ng-repeat) just to get the ng-model set to the ng-selected value in the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, maybe someone will find a way, but I don't think it is possible without ng-options

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` and it will automatically select the value present in `ng-model`.

If this doesn't work for you, please add more details like your JS code specially, your ng-model object.

A fiddle or plunker would be best.

---

Since you are so keen in using `ng-repeat` and not `ng-options`, here is how you can achieve it:

In your controller add the below code:

```
$scope.model={};

for(var i=0;i<$scope.options.length;i++){
  var selectedOption = $scope.options[i].selected;
  if(selectedOption != null && selectedOption == "selected"){
    $scope.model.string = $scope.options[i].name
  }
}
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/V6ogGyksHlAWrgtDhkMU?p=preview

Comment: ng-options is not an option (no pun intended). I'll make a plunkr.

Comment: If there is really no "clean" way I'll just accept that and do it that way.